# Transpose a matrix c++

Tags: c++11

I am trying to transpose a matrix but i am still getting this error

1 2

5 6

6 8 9

Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)

i get this when the program is trying to excute this line "trans[j][i] = a[i][j]" in the function

```
# include <vector>
# include <iostream>
using namespace std ;
void transpose(vector<vector<int>> a){
    vector<vector<int>>  trans;
    for (int i = 0; i <a.size() ; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j <a[i].size() ; ++j) {
            trans[j][i] = a[i][j];
        }
    }
}
int main () {
    vector<vector<int>> matrix = {{1, 2},{5, 6},{6, 8 ,9}};
    for (int i = 0; i < matrix.size(); ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < matrix[i].size(); ++j) {
            cout << matrix[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    transpose(matrix);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: vector<vector<int>>  trans;
This only defines a trans matrix, but doesn't allocate memory to the elements
So the statement
    trans[j][i] = a[i][j];
will give runtime error.
You need to ensure that trans matrix is allocated memory for its elements.

Comment: `vector<vector<int>>  trans` is initialized with zero elements, so `trans[j][i] = a[i][j];` assigns to out of bounds.

Comment: i tried to allocate memory for the matrix using resize() and reserve() but it also did not work.